# Use org.json with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson2, org.json

I am using *Spring Boot* framework and trying to create a structure where the developer can only return `org.json.JSONObject` instance. I have this endpoint declaration.

```java
    @RequestMapping(path = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public org.json.JSONObject hello(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
```

This always returns `{"empty":false}` because *Jackson* used by the framework does not know how to serialize the `org.json` instance. I am trying to tell *Jackson* how to serialize the `org.json` instance by using the following dependency.

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I cannot get it work unless I change the return type to `Map` value which is not possible. Using

```java
    ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .addModule(new JsonOrgModule())
        .build()
```

does not help. Is there a global `ObjectMapper` object that is used by Spring Boot where I can register the `JsonOrgModule` at the application startup? How can I use `org.json.JSONObject` return type using *Spring Boot* framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per [Spring Boot docs 4.3 Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.spring-mvc):

> Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module are
> automatically registered with the auto-configured
> Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and are applied to any ObjectMapper
> instances that it creates. This provides a global mechanism for
> contributing custom modules when you add new features to your
> application.

Therefore, if you provide a `@Bean` of type `JsonOrgModule` it will be automatically applied to the default `ObjectMapper` created at startup.

For example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonOrgModule jsonOrgModule() {
        return new JsonOrgModule();
    }

}

@SpringBootTest
class ObjectMapperTests {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

    @Test
    void defaultObjectMapperShouldWriteJsonObject() throws JSONException, JsonProcessingException {
        // Given
        var jsonObject = new JSONObject().put("username", "eHayik");

        // When
       var json = defaultObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonObject);

       // Then
       assertThat(json).isEqualTo("{\"username\":\"eHayik\"}");
    }
}
```